# How to specify Native Language in Flutter Create?

Tags: flutter

The command `flutter create [project-name]` used to create a new Flutter project, creates the Android code base in Kotlin.

Is there a way where we can ask Flutter to use Java as the preferred Android language?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is (`-a, --android-language`):

```
flutter create <project_name> -a java
```

Same goes for the *iOS language* (`-i, --ios-language`), which is `swift` by default:

```
flutter create <project_name> --android-language java --ios-language objc
```

You can always view the help page using `-h, --help`:

```
flutter create -h
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked with below command.

`flutter create --android-language java --ios-language objc first_app`

[image]